Beveling a sharp edge
I am trying to round the corners of this mesh to match with the background image. This is the result:.   The mesh was converted from bezier curves.

When you convert a curve into a mesh, the vertices of faces on top and bottom to "close" the mesh are usually not merged with the vertices of the curve outline.
So after converting the curve press Tab to go into Edit Mode, select all with A and then press M > Merge > By Distance.
But the top faces are also split up in triangles, so after merging all press X > Limited Dissolve and in the options at the bottom left of the viewport set a low Max Angle to make sure you do not loose edges on curves with low angles.

